# Google Camera API app crashes upon reentering

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-camera

I'm making a very basic camera app using Google's camera API. 
Initially launching the app is fine, but upon leaving and reentering, it crashes. I have found similar answers but I couldn't apply them to my specific code/situation. I have also tried messing around with onPause(), onResume, etc. but to no avail. Why is this happening and how can I fix this?

Below are the relevant methods and error log.

SurfaceView class:

```
public class ImageSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private Camera camera;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private String TAG = ImageSurfaceView.class.getSimpleName();

public ImageSurfaceView(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.camera = camera;
    surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    try {
            this.camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            this.camera.startPreview();
            this.camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

    if (holder.getSurface() == null){
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }

    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e){
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }
    try {
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> supportedPreviewSizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size camPreviewSize = getOptimalPreviewSize(supportedPreviewSizes, width , height);

        params.setPreviewSize(camPreviewSize.width ,camPreviewSize.height);
        camera.setParameters(params);
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting camera parameters: " + e.getMessage());
    }


    try {
       camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
       camera.startPreview();

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}
private void stopPreviewAndFreeCamera() {

    if (camera != null) {
        // Call stopPreview() to stop updating the preview surface.
       camera.stopPreview();

        // Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
        // applications. Applications should release the camera immediately
        // during onPause() and re-open() it during onResume()).
        camera.release();

       camera = null;
    }
}
private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h) {
    final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
    double targetRatio=(double)h / w;

    if (sizes == null) return null;

    Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
    double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

    int targetHeight = h;

    for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
        double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
        if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) continue;
        if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
            optimalSize = size;
            minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
        }
    }

    if (optimalSize == null) {
        minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }
    }
    return optimalSize;
}
```

}

onPause/onResume

```
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d(TAG, " -> onPause");
    if(camera != null){
        releaseCamera();
    }
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, " <- onPause");

}
private void releaseCamera(){
    if (camera != null){

       camera.release(); 
        camera = null;
    }
}
 @Override
public void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
         Log.d(TAG, " -> OnResume");
       if (camera == null) {
           camera = checkDeviceCamera();
       }

         Log.d(TAG, " <- OnResume");
 }
```

Camera methods:

```
private Camera checkDeviceCamera(){
    Camera mCamera = null;
    try {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mCamera;
}
private void startCamera() {

    camera = checkDeviceCamera();

    mImageSurfaceView = new ImageSurfaceView(MainActivity.this, camera);
    cameraPreviewLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview); //the framelayout
    cameraPreviewLayout.addView(mImageSurfaceView); //adding surfaceview to framelayout

    ImageButton captureButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureCallback);

        }
    });
}

Camera.PictureCallback pictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (camera != null) {
                    camera.startPreview();
                }
            }
        }, 0);
    }
};
```

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: daniel816.com.danger, PID: 10594
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera is being used after Camera.release() was called
                  at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewSurface(Native Method)
                  at android.hardware.Camera.setPreviewDisplay(Camera.java:738)
                  at danielwei816.com.danger.ImageSurfaceView.surfaceCreated(ImageSurfaceView.java:33)
                  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:634)
                  at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:256)
                  at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:10293)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1289)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1289)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1289)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1289)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1289)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1289)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1289)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1599)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1299)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6558)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
                  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
                  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have lifecycle of your activity (onResume, onPause etc.) and lifecycle of your SurfaceView (surfaceChanged, surfaceDestroyed etc.). 
You release your camera in onPause, but you stop it in surfaceDestroyed (which is called later). I think this is the problem.